# How can I change a menu from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-menu

In a fragment I see in the `onCreate` `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`
I see the menu.
But I can't understand, if I need to change something in the menu where should I do that programmatically?
Now I see a menu which I am not sure which resource file is loaded but how can I change/update the menu *before* it is actually rendered e.g. to remove an item?

**Update:** I don't need todo this from the fragment. The hosting activity is fine but I don't know where should I do this and how

Answer (score 2):

You can override [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)), which is called before the menu is displayed and everytime you call [FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()). There you can call [setVisible()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)) to hide or show menu items as needed.

Comment: But that is for 1 menu of the action bar right? I want to hide 1 menu from the bar. Not 1 item from the menu

Comment: `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` gives you the entire `Menu` back, including all things added to it from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` - you'd use [findItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)) to retrieve as many menu items as you'd like.

Comment: So why then override the `onPrepareOptions` and not change `onCreateOptions`?

Comment: Per the Javadoc on the method: "You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents."

Comment: One more question. I don't understand how it knows which resource file to load to show the menu. Is it something like a "convention"?

Comment: It loads the menu you specify in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: But I only see: `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` there

Comment: Then something else has an `onCreateOptionsMenu()` that is adding the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change something in the menu where should I do that programmatically?

While menu is not managed by your fragment, I'd suggest to make fragment calling host Activity's method of your choice to request the change, but the change itself should be done by Activity

Comment: That is fine but where in the activity?